# LINQ to Data : Clever Type Recognition

Tags: c#, linq, types, casting

Working on Maths problems, I'm very fond of LINQ to Data.

I would like to know if LINQ is smart enough to avoid a cast like .ToArray() when the IEnumerable I work with is already an array.
See example below:

```
/// <summary> Transforms an array of timeSeries into one ModelData. </summary>
public static ModelData ToModelData(this IEnumerable<TimeSerieInfo> timeSeries)
{
    var seriesArray = timeSeries as TimeSerieInfo[];
    return null != seriesArray ? 
        new ModelData(seriesArray) : 
        new ModelData(timeSeries.ToArray());
}
```

Does LINQ avoid the transformation to an array when the `IEnumerable<TimeSerieInfo> timeSeries` is already an array?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you mean LINQ to Objects, or is there some other LINQ provider around called LINQ to Data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ creates a copy of the array, *and this is the correct behaviour* IMO. It would be highly confusing if calling `ToArray()` and then modifying the returned array *sometimes* modified the original collection and *sometimes* didn't.

Comment: That's logic. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it will do what you ask and create a new array. Could you not change your constructor of `ModelData` to take an `IEnumerable` instead?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ does create a copy of the array; it creates a `System.Linq.Buffer<T>`, which creates a copy of the array.

You can create your own extension method though:

```
public static TSource[] ToArrayPreserved<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return (source as TSource[]) ??  source.ToArray();
}
```